# WebApp with only 1 div viewed

Tags: web-applications, html

I'm trying to create an webapp and searched around to find tutorials... I found "jquery" and noticed as I looked at the code, that there aren't single websites, only some divs that created the single sites... How is that done? When I create a website with divs they are on one website.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. I'm not sure what you're asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, my English isn't that good: I just wanted to know how I can manage it to create a website with multiple sites like www.lalalala.com/site1 and www.lalalala.com/site2 but turn it to /#site1 and /#site2. So that in one HTML file there is one body element with some div, which represent each one single site. Like in the demo of the jquery WebApp.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is identify what text is coming after the hash tag in the url and show/hide certain divs accordingly.

You can do this easily with jQuery. Below is an extremely rough example I wrote up, but should give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

**index.html#home** will display "Content from page 1"

**index.html#about** will display "Content from page 2"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="home_content_div" class="content_divs">
        Content from page 1
    </div>
    <div id="about_content_div" class="content_divs">
        Content from page 2
    </div>

    <script>
         var identifier = window.location.hash;

         $(".content_divs").hide();
         if (identifier === "#home") {
             $("#home_content_div").show();
         }
         else if (identifier === "#about") {
             $("#about_content_div").show();
         }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```